# Copy files using SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, copy, scp, transfer

I'm trying copy file from remote server from my pc using SSH connections, but  don't work.

```
scp userremote@serverremotename:filename /home/user/Desktop/
```

The result is: No Such file or directory

What is wrong??

Tks,
Rod

Comment: your file `/home/user/Desktop/` does not exist on your local computer. Copying to CWD should do the job: `scp userremote@serverremotename:filename ./`

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se] or [su]. You should also include the full error message being printed by scp, instead of paraphrasing it.

Comment: It's copy the file to the serverremote, don't from my local machine, I'm logged with putty on my server remote , I need to download the file to my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give Full path of the `filename`. If it is in `tmp` folder you can write like this

```
scp userremote@serverremotename:/tmp/filename /home/user/Desktop/
```

Comment: not working!


    /home/user/Desktop/ - no Such file or directory

Comment: "user" should be replaced with actual username. This is the only thing that attracts my attention. Please check